# Django локализация и пути

Tags: django

Подскажите плиз, делаю сайт на двух языках. По умолчанию django для каждого языка подставляет корневой путь /ru/ или /en/
А как сделать чтобы для языка по умолчанию (ru) адреса выводились от корня /, а для английского через /en/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решено!
Необходимо добавить в i18n_patterns дополнительный параметр prefix_default_language=False. В итоге код корневого urls выглядит как показано ниже

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(

    url(r'^$', home_page, name='home_page'),
    # ...

    prefix_default_language=False,
)
```

Comment: У меня это решение не работает

Comment: К сожалению, сейчас не могу сказать с чем именно это связанно. Решение точно работало для той версии Django корорую я использовал 5.5 лет назад, когда опубликовал вопрос. Уже несколько лет пишу только на Go. Надеюсь вы найдете актуальное решение этой проблемы

Comment: Нужно добавить в settings.py вот это LANGUAGE_CODE='en' #required language